# CSS/HTML popup won't close

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement a popup by hand using html, css and some jquery functions.

My logic: when I click the initial div I want it to increase its size and make visible a cancel button, which it works. What it does not work is to close the popup by clicking the remove button.

My html:

```
<div class="google-maps-div" id="popup">
    <div class="google-maps-remove-button" id="popup-button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

My scripts:

```
$(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.google-maps-div').click(function () {
                $('#popup').removeClass('google-maps-div');
                $('#popup').addClass('google-maps-div-popup');
                $('.google-maps-remove-button').css("visibility", "visible");
            })
        })
    })



$(function () {
        $('.google-maps-remove-button').click(function () {
            console.log("Cancel clicked !");
            $('#popup').removeClass('google-maps-div-popup');
            $('#popup').addClass('google-maps-div');
            $('.google-maps-remove-button').css("visibility", "hidden");
        })
    })
```

My CSS:

```
.google-maps-div{
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0;
     right: 0;
     margin-right: 15px;
     margin-bottom: 15px;
     width: 250px;
     height: 150px;
     background-color: yellow;
     border: 1px solid #000000;
     border-radius: 7.5px 7.5px 7.5px 7.5px;
}

.google-maps-div-popup{
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 10%;
     top: 10%;
     width: 80%;
     left: 10%;
     right: 10%;
     height: 75%;
     background-color: yellow;
     border: 1px solid #000000;
     border-radius: 7.5px 7.5px 7.5px 7.5px;
 }

.google-maps-remove-button{
     position: relative;
     top: 2.5%;
     left: 97.5%;
     visibility: hidden;
 }
```

**Edit**: I want the popup div to go back to its initial size, forgot to mention this.

Thanks,
Marcus

Comment: `$('.popup').hide();` Try

Comment: i don't see anything like `display:none;` in your CSS. So how the popup is going to be hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably when clicking the button it also trigger the other click event handler ( attached to `'.google-maps-div'`), so what happens is that popup close and reopen immediately.

Try using `e.stopPropagation();` to prevent that behaviour. Like this

```
$(function () {
        $('.google-maps-remove-button').click(function (e) {
            console.log("Cancel clicked !");
            $('#popup').addClass('google-maps-div');
            $('#popup').removeClass('google-maps-div-popup');
            $('.google-maps-remove-button').css("visibility", "hidden");
            e.stopPropagation();
        })
    })
```

see this [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ey1fzuj6/)

Answer (score 0):

You are changing css of button itself

```
$('.google-maps-remove-button').css("visibility", "hidden");
```

Use below code to hide popup

```
$('#popup').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply new CSS and class toggle **after some time** as below.

```
$('.google-maps-remove-button').click(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#popup').removeClass('google-maps-div-popup');
            $('#popup').addClass('google-maps-div');
            $('.google-maps-remove-button').css("visibility", "hidden");
        }, 100);           

    })
```